# Set Witness server on Principal got error

Tags: sql-server, database, mirroring

I was setting up database mirroring, here is my model:

- Pricipal database instance in server1
- Mirror database instance in
  server2
- Witness database instance in server2

I was setting up mirroring with certificate, it is ok when I set Principal and Mirror see together.

But when I add Witness for Principal, I got an error:

"The ALTER DATABASE command could not be sent to the remote server instance 'TCP://xxx:5024'. The database mirroring configuration was not changed. Verify that the server is connected, and try again."

Notice that I was setting up the correct certificate for Principal, Mirror and Witness
And the Principal can telnet to Witness via 5024 port.

I have been searching on the internet for two weeks but it seems there is no complete answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent one day to figure out this issue and this thread [Trouble setting up witness in SQL Server mirroring scheme w/ error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691017/trouble-setting-up-witness-in-sql-server-mirroring-scheme-w-error?rq=1)
 saved me.

My problem is the Witness server does not see the Principal server. I went through the Windows Event in Witness server and see this:

The mirroring connection to "TCP://xx:6022" has timed out for database "xxx" after 10 seconds without a response.  Check the service and network connections.

And I add a host entry point to Principle server on Witness server and problem solved.